# Why is the set of even degree polynomials on [-1, 1] not closed in C[-1, 1]?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $$E = \{\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^{2k}|n\in N \cup \{0\}\}$$ Why is E not closed in C[-1, 1]?

I have some ideas...Is it because that

1. if I create a sequence exactly like E and let n goes to infinity thus this sequence does not converge...? I was trying to connect it to its limit point.

or 2. Let $fn(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$,...then it might converge to  e? (I think it's wrong but might be closer to the answer.)

3. Might have something to do with Stone-Weierstrass Thm? Because E does not separate points.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2n)!}$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)= \cos x$ on $[-1,1]$.

Hence $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0$.

We have $f_n \in E$ for all $n$, but $f \notin E$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f\in C[-1,1]$ such that $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ For every $r>0$ there is  a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<r$ for all $x\in [0,1].$

Let $q(x)=(p(x)+p(-x))/2.$ For all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $$|f(x)-q(x)|=|(f(x)+f(-x))/2-(p(x)+p(-x))/2|=$$ $$=|(f(x)-p(x))/2+(f(-x)-p(-x))/2|\leq$$ $$\leq |f(x)-p(x)|/2+|f(-x)-p(-x)|/2<r.$$

For every odd $n$ the coefficient of $x^n$ in $q$ is $0$. So $q\in E$.  So $f\in \bar E.$ For example if $f(x)=|x|$ then $f\in \bar E.$